# Is it possible to check if an email contains an attachement just from the e-mail header?

Tags: python, email, imap, imaplib

I am developing an email client in Python.

Is it possible to check if an email contains an attachement just from the e-mail header without downloading the whole E-Mail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"attachment" is quite a broad term. Is an image for HTML message an attachment?

In general, you can try analyzing content-type header. If it's *multipart/mixed*, most likely the message contains an attachment.

Comment: yes its true , but its not always :)
so is there any perfect solution ?

Comment: I suppose the trouble with multipart/mixed is that people use it to send HTML emails with those dreadful image signature blocks on. There's no way to tell those from an attachment without looking quite closely.

Comment: Exactly, with HTML e-mails, images (technically) are attachments as well, and if we think deeper, they *are* attachments, as they are local and not external entities.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp What if they are Base64 encoded?

Comment: @sashoalm so what? Encoding doesn't change the nature of attachments. Analysis of the content/type of the part is the only way to understand what is contained in the message part and if it can be treated as an attachment.

Answer (score 7):

Try `IMAP4.fetch(message_set, "BODYSTRUCTURE")`

Read the [RFC3501](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html) for details about the FETCH BODYSTRUCTURE response.